# редактирование громкости аудио с помощью питона

Tags: python, moviepy

Можно ли с помощью библиотеки moviepy редактировать громкость аудио не могу найти в документации.

Или можете подсказать библиотеку, которая может выполнять данную задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это действительно можно сделать, воспользовавшись библиотекой pycaw

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
volume.GetMute()
volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()
volume.GetVolumeRange()
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-20.0, None)
```